# Can I rescore on the basis of max score and/or max value of my custom field in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

All I want to do is re-score my query according to this formula,

NEW SCORE = OLD SCORE/max(OLD SCORES) + doc.value['custom']/max(doc.value['custom'])

Is this possible? I am able to rescore using the following code

```
{ 
      "query": {
      "function_score": {
      "query": {}
     , "script_score": {
       "script": "_score * doc['custom'].value"
       }
      }
     }
 }
```

Also, it would be great if someone could tell how to use values of one script in another.

Comment: Any news on this issue?

Comment: Can't find a way to achieve it. Seems impossible in one execution, as the query should have a way to (know or) calculate the max value of the custom field first. Only then it would be able to rescore.

Comment: No luck on my part too, I believe one has to reimplement scoring to handle this ...

Answer (score 0):

Not sure it would feet your need, but maybe you could use some *flattening* application, where you would force max score to be 1, assuming that you can find a score value (score_thresh) above which results are good anyway and your field `doc.value['custom']` will do the ranking job.

A method such as:

```
1 / (score_thresh - min(_score, score_thresh - 1))
```

would do the trick, but be a bit harsh on your score curve. It does work for me as all I want from my old_score is to select documents, a rescore query taking care of the ranking.